# Submitting a job on SGE using qsub

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments, sungridengine

I am trying to submit my script to SGE on my local server but for some reason the system is not recognizing the option.

My submission looks as such:
qsub ./script.sh

From what I have read online this should work. Does anyone know why it isn't working? What is the correct syntax for submitting jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without "./", the argument should be the path to the script:

```
qsub script.sh
```